# Restore Amazon RDS from snapshot via Java API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've a script which start an amazon RDS from a previous snapshot.
Now i've to implement this functionality with the Java API.

The script I run is :

```
rds-restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot $RDS_DEV --db-snapshot-identifier $SNAP --db-subnet-group-name $SUBNET_GROUP --region $REGION
echo sleep $TIME
```

So, after that i sleep a certain time then assign the right security group and parameter group:

```
rds-modify-db-instance $RDS_DEV --db-security-groups $SEC_GROUP --db-parameter-group-name $PARAM_GROUP --apply-immediately --region $REGION
```

then i reboot the instance.

In  my API implementation, i've crated this method to restore an RDS from a snapshot:

```
    public void restoreDBSnapshot(String rdsDev, String snapshotId,
        String subnetGroup, String availabilityZone) {
        RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshotRequest restoreDBInstanceRequest = new RestoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshotRequest();
         restoreDBInstanceRequest.setDBSnapshotIdentifier(snapshotId);
         restoreDBInstanceRequest.setDBName(rdsDev);
         restoreDBInstanceRequest.setDBSubnetGroupName(subnetGroup);
         restoreDBInstanceRequest.setAvailabilityZone(availabilityZone);
         LOG.info("Restoring RDS from backup snapshot");
         this.rds.restoreDBInstanceFromDBSnapshot(restoreDBInstanceRequest);
}
```

but i don't want to sleep my application waiting for the RDS startup
and then modify the securityGroup and the parameterGroupName with a

> ModifyDBInstanceRequest

Is there a solution to do it in creation phase?